# Can the Powered Up app be used to directly control the Boost Move Hub?

Tags: boost, powered-up

I have the LEGO Boost kit, and I'm wondering if I can control it directly using the Powered Up app rather than programming it using the Boost app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the Powered Up app version 3.0, this is possible.

---

Old answer:

As of August 2018, this is not possible. However, [TLG has stated](https://lan.lego.com/news/overview/powered-up-afol-community-answers-r146/) that they plan to add more compatibility to the Powered Up system, and this will likely be available as a firmware update in the future:

> Q. Will all different Powered Up components (Boost, WeDo, Train, etc)
>   be able to communicate and control each other, e.g. running a Boost
>   program sequence using a Powered Up hub or using sensors with Powered
>   Up hubs?
>
> A. It is the aim that the Powered UP platform will work together
>   across both with the wired and wireless connection. Some of these
>   connections are not implemented yet and will come through firmware and
>   app updates.

Answer (score 2):

On February 2020, this has been possible for a while now, and have been playing with it. (Power Up app version 3.0)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've updated my answer to reflect this information. Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Comment: Also: Next Logical step for someone is looking up block documentation... The best and currently only place is: https://racingbrick.com/powered-up-code-block-guide/ (related video : https://youtu.be/a4gWPey2sBE)